# Recursive Sequences Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_{n+1} = 0.25((a_n)^2+a_n+2)$, where $a_1 = 3$. By showing that $(a_n)$ is increasing, deduce that $(a_n)$ does not converge.

I showed that it is increasing by induction. For base case $3.5 \geq 3$ so true for $n=1$. Assume for some $k \in N$ that $a_{k+1} \geq a_k$. Now for inductive step, by assumption $a_{k+1} \geq a_k$, so $(a_{k+1})^2 \geq (a_k)^2$, so $(a_{k+1})^2 + a_{k+1} \geq (a_k)^2$ using assumption. In all, we end up with $0.25((a_{k+1})^2+a_{k+1}+2) \geq 0.25((a_n)^2+a_n+2)$ as required.

I then said that since $(a_n)$ is increasing and unbounded above, it clearly does not converge. However, am I not sure how to show that it is not unbounded above. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: solutions of $x=0.25(x^2+x+2)$ are $x=1$ and $x=2$

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence is increasing, $a_{n}\geq 3$ for all $n.$
Then $$a_{n+1} -a_n= 0.25(a_n-1)(a_n-2)\geq 0.5$$ for all $n.$
Consequently, the sequence is unbounded from above.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Since $a_{n}\geq 3$ we get $a_{n}^{2} \geq 3 a_{n}$ therefore $$a_{n+1}\geq\dots$$